# How to expand Rive animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, android-animation, rive

I want to make rive animation background and feel whole screen.
Changing height and width to MediaQuery... does not work. It changes size but proportion stays the same

This is how rive widget looks like for me:

```
Center(
            child: _riveArtboard == null
                ? const SizedBox()
                : Rive(artboard: _riveArtboard),
          ),
```

thank you in advance

edit:
**SOLUTION**

```
Container(
          height: h,
          width: w,
          child: Center(
            child: _riveArtboard == null
                ? const SizedBox()
                : Rive(fit: BoxFit.fill, artboard: _riveArtboard),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: yes, after a few tries and posting quests, I got it

Comment: @helloitsme3 can you please post your answer on the thread? You can mark your own answers as accepted and help other people with this issue :)

Comment: @IbrahimYildirim I edited question, there is solution in description :)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding height and width to his parent Container and add a fit(cover, fill, whatever you need) to your **Rive** widget

```
 Container(
           width: w,
           height: h,
           child: Rive(
               fit: BoxFit.cover,
               artboard: ctrl.globalArtboard!,
          ),
    ),
```